# set cookie on click with php

Tags: php, cookies

hi i want to set a cookie on button click but i have a problem with it
this is my first version of code and it is working fine

```html
<?php
$ID = is_numeric($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : 1;

$cookie_name = "favoritepost";

if ( isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    $kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
} else {
    $kookie = array();
}
if ( ! in_array($ID, $kookie) ) {
    $kookie[] = $ID;
}

setcookie($cookie_name, serialize($kookie), time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
```

then as i said i wanted to change the cookie set as button click so i wrote this code but it is not workinf and it gives me no cookie set what is the problem. thanks

```html
<!doctype html>
<?php
$ID = is_numeric($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : 1;

$cookie_name = "favoritepost";

if ( isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    $kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
} else {
    $kookie = array();
}
if ( ! in_array($ID, $kookie) ) {
    $kookie[] = $ID;
}
?>

<button type="button" onclick="setcookie('<?php echo $cookie_name;?>', '<?php echo serialize($kookie);?>', time() + (86400 * 30), "/")">Click Me!</button> 
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing **JS** and **PHP**, and it's a deadly combination. JS is a client-side language where as PHP is a sever side language.

Every thing you write in **PHP** is executed server and everything your write in **JS** is executed client side.

---

First solution is use **AJAX** calls to connect **PHP** script with **JS**. Call AJAX function on click of a button which calls PHP script on server side to save the cookie.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_php.asp

---

Another solution is perform operations on client side only to save/retrive cookie.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

---

> Doing it on server-side is preferable as it gives more security then
>   client side code.

Comment: thank you for your answering let me study a little about ajax i will edit my code and then please tell me your opinion